# c# - Store a collection of handlers mapped to the concrete type they operate on

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I am adding metrics tracking to my application. For each concrete Metric object there is a specific MetricsTracker that is responsible for parsing the data and sending it off to the server. I originally wanted to use generics for each MetricsTracker, but I ran into an issue during the design, and cannot figure out an elegant solution. I've created a simplified model to illustrate where I am stuck.

Lets pretend I am running a a zoo, when I notice that one of the animals is sick, I will need to find a zoo keeper who specializes in caring for that animal.

Here is my Animal class. It contains a ZooCode which is used by the zoo to identify it. (Note the "ZooCode" is necessary in my real model because it identifies a metric type on the server)

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    //The zoo code of this animal. 
    public abstract int ZooCode { get; }

    //other things specific to an animal. 
}
```

Here is an example of a concrete Animal.

```
public class Elephant : Animal
{
    //An Elephant has a zoo code of 1
    public override string ZooCode { get { return 1; } }
}
```

Here is the base class for a ZooKeeper, a ZooKeeper only knows how to care for a specific type of Animal.

```
public abstract class ZooKeeper
{
    //The Zoo Code of the animal we care for. 
    public abstract int AnimalTendsTo { get; }

    //Tend to our animals needs
    public abstract void CareForAnimal(Animal animal);
}
```

Here is an example of a concrete ZooKeeper.

```
public class ElephantKeeper : ZooKeeper
{
    //We care for elephants, they have ZooCode of '1' 
    public override int AnimalTendsTo
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }

    public override void CareForAnimal(Animal animal)
    {
        //cast animmal as elephant, then feed peanuts.
    }
}
```

Now when I notice an Animal is sick, I go to the ZooKeeperManagers office and I tell them which Animal needs to be treated. It is the responsibility of the ZooKeeperManager to find the ZooKeeper which specializes in the sick Animal.

```
public class ZooKeeperManager
{   
    /// <summary>
    /// All of the ZooKeepers, mapped to the ZooCode of the animal they 
    /// care for. 
    /// </summary>
    private Dictionary<int, ZooKeeper> _zooKeepers;

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when we hire a new zoo keeper. 
    /// </summary>
    public void RegisterZooKeeper(ZooKeeper newbie)
    {
        //data validation, etc...

        //store our new zookeeper. 
        _zooKeepers.Add(newbie.AnimalTendsTo, newbie);
    }


    public void CareForAnimal(Animal animal)
    {
        //An animal needs care, find the ZooKeeper that can care for it. 
        ZooKeeper careTaker;

        if (_zooKeepers.TryGetValue(animal.ZooCode, out careTaker) == false)
            return;

        careTaker.CareForAnimal(animal);

    }
}
```

---

Here is where I am unhappy with my design! I originally intended for ZooKeeper to be Generic, that way a ZooKeeper got a reference to the Concrete Animal that it cared for, and it didn't have to worry about specifying ZooCodes or casting its Animal to the correct type. Here is what I first came up with..

```
public abstract class ZooKeeper<T>
    where T : Animal
{
    //Tend to our animals needs
    public abstract void CareForAnimal(T animal);
}
```

A ZooKeeperManager needs to know about which ZooKeepers care for which Animal.. I really like the idea of a ZooKeeperManager being able to say "Oh an Elephant is sick?? Well that means I need THIS ZooKeeper" however I couldn't figure out an elegant way to store ZooKeepers when they are generic. This is where I got stuck:

```
public class ZooKeeperManager
{   
    /// <summary>
    /// All of the ZooKeepers, mapped to the ZooCode of the animal they 
    /// care for. 
    /// </summary>
    private List<ZooKeeper<Animal>> _zooKeepers;

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when we hire a new zoo keeper. 
    /// </summary>
    public void RegisterZooKeeper(ZooKeeper<Animal> newbie)
    {
        //data validation, etc...

        //store our new zookeeper. 
        _zooKeepers.Add(newbie);
    }


    public void CareForAnimal(Animal animal)
    {
        //How do I find the Zoo Keeper that Cares for this Animal?? 
        //A List definitely isn't what I want.. I won't have o(1) Lookup, plus how do I know
        //Which concrete Animal that ZooKeeper cares about?
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could store a collection in my ZooKeeperManager which maps a ZooKeeper to the type of Animal they care for?

Comment: Have you thought of inheriting from `KeyedCollection<int, Animal>` for the `ZooKeeperManager` so you don't do a `List<>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, yes, it's possible, first you must implement a base ZooKeeper:

```
public class ZooKeeperBase
{ }
```

And your abstract ZooKeeper must inherit it:

```
public abstract class ZooKeeper<T> : ZooKeeperBase
where T : Animal
{
    //Tend to our animals needs
    public abstract void CareForAnimal(T animal);
}
```

Finally you modify your Manager to store ZooKeeperBase's instances and use boxing and a generic function when you must take care of your Animal:

```
private List<ZooKeeperBase> _zooKeepers = new List<ZooKeeperBase>();

public void CareForAnimal<T>(T animal) where T : Animal
    {
        //How do I find the Zoo Keeper that Cares for this Animal?? 
        //A List definitely isn't what I want.. I won't have o(1) Lookup, plus how do I know
        //Which concrete Animal that ZooKeeper cares about?

        foreach (ZooKeeperBase keeper in _zooKeepers)
        {

            var thisKeeper = keeper as ZooKeeper<T>;

            if (thisKeeper != null)
            {

                thisKeeper.CareForAnimal(animal);
                return;

            }

        }
    }
```

For clarity I'm posting the full model and a test class.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    //The zoo code of this animal. 
    public abstract int ZooCode { get; }

    //other things specific to an animal. 
}

public class Elephant : Animal
{
    //An Elephant has a zoo code of 1
    public override int ZooCode { get { return 1; } }
}

public class ZooKeeperBase
{ }

public abstract class ZooKeeper<T> : ZooKeeperBase
where T : Animal
{
    //Tend to our animals needs
    public abstract void CareForAnimal(T animal);
}

public class ElephantKeeper : ZooKeeper<Elephant>
{
    public override void CareForAnimal(Elephant animal)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi elephant! take some peanuts.");
    }
}

public class ZooKeeperManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// All of the ZooKeepers, mapped to the ZooCode of the animal they 
    /// care for. 
    /// </summary>
    private List<ZooKeeperBase> _zooKeepers = new List<ZooKeeperBase>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when we hire a new zoo keeper. 
    /// </summary>
    public void RegisterZooKeeper(ZooKeeperBase newbie)
    {
        //data validation, etc...

        //store our new zookeeper. 
        _zooKeepers.Add(newbie);
    }


    public void CareForAnimal<T>(T animal) where T : Animal
    {
        //How do I find the Zoo Keeper that Cares for this Animal?? 
        //A List definitely isn't what I want.. I won't have o(1) Lookup, plus how do I know
        //Which concrete Animal that ZooKeeper cares about?

        foreach (ZooKeeperBase keeper in _zooKeepers)
        {

            var thisKeeper = keeper as ZooKeeper<T>;

            if (thisKeeper != null)
            {

                thisKeeper.CareForAnimal(animal);
                return;

            }

        }
    }
}

public static class ZooKeepingSystemTest
{ 

    public static void KeepIt()
    {
        ZooKeeperManager manager = new ZooKeeperManager();

        ElephantKeeper keeper = new ElephantKeeper();

        manager.RegisterZooKeeper(keeper);

        manager.CareForAnimal(new Elephant());

    }

}
```

**EDIT:** Did not noticed the comment about not using a list, indeed its possible, in this example I'm using a dictionary to store a list of all the ZooKeepers which take care of a concrete animal so we can use anyone of them randomly (if you only have a keeper for each animal type you can add the keeper directly to the Dictionary), only the ZooKeeperManager must be modified.

```
public class ZooKeeperManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// All of the ZooKeepers, mapped to the Animal's full class name they
    /// care for. 
    /// </summary>
    private Dictionary<string, List<ZooKeeperBase>> _zooKeepers = new Dictionary<string, List<ZooKeeperBase>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when we hire a new zoo keeper. 
    /// </summary>
    public void RegisterZooKeeper<T>(ZooKeeper<T> newbie) where T : Animal
    {
        //data validation, etc...

        var type = typeof(T);

        List<ZooKeeperBase> keeperPool = null;

        if (_zooKeepers.ContainsKey(type.FullName))
            keeperPool = _zooKeepers[type.FullName];
        else
        {

            keeperPool = new List<ZooKeeperBase>();
            _zooKeepers.Add(type.FullName, keeperPool);
        }

        //store our new zookeeper. 
        keeperPool.Add(newbie);
    }


    public void CareForAnimal<T>(T animal) where T : Animal
    {

        var type = typeof(T);

        if (!_zooKeepers.ContainsKey(type.FullName))
            throw new Exception("We don't know how to care that animal!");

        Random rnd = new Random();

        ((ZooKeeper<T>)(_zooKeepers[type.FullName].OrderBy(k => rnd.NextDouble()).First())).CareForAnimal(animal); ;

    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much. I was actually modifying your solution to use a Dictionary before I saw your edit. I was going to add an abstract property to ZooKeeperBase which returned the System.Type of the Animal that it specializes in. However I like the way you suggested much better because it keeps that responsibility in ZooKeeperManager, plus having a System.Type property in ZooKeeperBase definitely felt weird.